# open /bin/migrate: operation not permitted when building Go tags

Tags: mysql, go

I'm following this Go + GraphQL tutorial https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-go/4-database/ and I got stuck at the point where I'm trying to install and then run migrations.

The entire command chain is

```
go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
go build -tags 'mysql' -ldflags="-X main.Version=1.0.0" -o $GOPATH/bin/migrate github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate/
cd internal/pkg/db/migrations/
migrate create -ext sql -dir mysql -seq create_users_table
migrate create -ext sql -dir mysql -seq create_links_table
```

But specifically in

```
go build -tags 'mysql' -ldflags="-X main.Version=1.0.0" -o $GOPATH/bin/migrate github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate/
cd internal/pkg/db/migrations/
```

I will get the following error in my terminal:

```
go build github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate: copying /var/folders/f9/d6pn7fz92w53vcpywqd_08zm0000gp/T/go-build1656176552/b001/exe/a.out: open /bin/migrate: operation not permitted
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$GOPATH` is not set (which is fine and `go` will fallback to default value).

That causes `$GOPATH/bin/migrate` evaluate to `/bin/migrate` instead of its expected value - something like `/home/you/go/bin/migrate` (where `/home/you/go` is default `$GOPATH`).

To use the default value in case `$GOPATH` is not set; your `go build` command should call `$(go env GOPATH)` instead of using `$GOPATH` directly:

```bash
go build -tags 'mysql' -ldflags="-X main.Version=1.0.0" -o $(go env GOPATH)/bin/migrate github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate/
```

That tutorial is simply making wrong assumption that `$GOPATH` environment variable is always set.